# Lambda Sagemaker Dependencies

Tags: python, pip, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to download the dependencies for my lambda function (the sagemaker package) in either a Notebook instance or a Sagemaker studio instance. I'm running:

```
!conda install -y -c conda-forge zip
!mkdir ./lambda-package
!pip install sagemaker -t ./lambda-package
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
!pip install -r requirements.txt -t ./lambda-package
!cd lambda-package && zip -r ./sagemaker-package.zip .
```

and I'm able to include this in my deployment package and get my lambda to run but now I'm getting the error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': 
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:
  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.8"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.6"
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there a way to make sure I install using python 3.8? Should I use Conda? I'm trying to avoid having to install conda locally and it would be great if I could download the dependencies via a remote AWS source, I'm just wondering if this is possible or not or if I'll have to go through setting up a local env.

Comment: you wouldn't need conda. just make sure your host python version is 3.8 before you run the pip install.  I believe the above error is mainly due to mismatch in python version between the packages in zip and the lambda runtime.